# What's the Sanskrit word for maintaining distance with relatives of the deceased?

Tags: death

What's the Sanskrit word for theetu (as used in apara kaaryam) as  tamil brahmins say ?.What is the duration of  theetu relatives- wise ?

Comment: Your question in title asks whats the rules and in body you are asking for sanskrit word for theetu. Mismatching!

Comment: @AkshayS sorry I am a new comer .Will edit

Comment: The sankrt word is Asaucha.It comes from Asuchi.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda tq bro

Comment: @Partha thanks brother.They say naazhigai duration relatives wise.Any idea ?

Comment: @SrinivasanSundaram no i dont think its a sanskrit word:) But my knowledge is limited

Comment: @Partha Naazhigai tamil word .They say one naazhigai is 24 minutes so totally 60 naazhigai in a day .They prescribe certain naazhigai duration for asaucha which I asked for

Comment: Hi bro, when did you join this site? Unfortunately, your first question is off-topic lol

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury 